# Why can't I manage the state in my modal to open and close using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want the modal to appear when the user clicks `Checkout` which's inside `<CheckoutButton/>` component below.

Instead what's happening is that the modal appears upon reloading my browser, which's the opposite of what I want to happen.  What am I doing wrong in my `List.js` file and/or `reducer.js`

Here's my `List.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

import FoodButton from '../FoodButtons/FoodButton';

class List extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    }

    toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({isActive:!this.state.isActive});
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({isActive: false});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <CheckoutButton clicked={this.toggleModal}/>

                <Modal isOpen={() => this.props.openModalRedux()}>
                    <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        mClose: state.mClose.closed
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        openModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: OPEN_MODAL})
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List);
```

Here's my `reducer.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as actionTypes from '../action/NoNameAction';

const initialState = {
    isActive: false
};

const modalOpen = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.OPEN_MODAL:
            return {
                ...state
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default modalOpen;
```

Here's the `CheckoutButton.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';

const checkoutButton = (props) => (
    <Aux>
        <button onClick={props.clicked}>Checkout</button>
    </Aux>
);

export default checkoutButton;
```

Comment: `isOpen` should only be given a boolean saying if the modal should be shown or not. You are using `setState` which sets the state of the component, but you are not using anything that is given to the component from `react-redux`.

Comment: I guess, Modal isOpen attr in your List render method should be a boolean variable that comes from redux store

Comment: @dhilt yeah that's what I tried to do with `isActive: false` inside `reducer.js` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I see the problem. Just provide accurate binding of react-modal `isOpen` attribute with appropriate value from redux.

List render method

```
<Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
    ...
</Modal>
```

List mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isOpen: state.global.isModalOpen
    }
};
```

Reducer (global)

```
const initialState = {
    isModalOpen: false
};

const global = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.OPEN_MODAL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isModalOpen: true,
            }
        case actionTypes.CLOSE_MODAL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isModalOpen: false,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work :( I get an error that says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isModalOpen' of undefined`.  I changed my root reducer inside the `index.js` file too, so that's not the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it the error from `mapStateToProps`? you need to setup the reducer appropriately. I can't provide all necessary infrastructure...

Comment: yeah, the error is from `mapStateToProps `.  I guess you're right, thanks for your input.

Comment: @sp92 Also, it would be very helpful if you could provide a demo of your issue on stackblitz, plunker or whatever. In that case the problem could be fixed precisely (not only conceptually).